# Kusto/KQL Query to aggregate stringcolumn into bins

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a kusto data table containing a column of type string. I want to aggregate the string column into bins of 1 minute, using the last known value of the string. If it has no value in the bin, i want to use the values of the last bin/row. I also want to Count the Quality column for each bin.

Source Data Table:
[image]

Source table as Kusto data table:

```
datatable (StartTimestamp: datetime, ValueString: string, Quality: string) [
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:14:00.000000Z),"AAA","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:16:00.000000Z),"BBB","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:20:00.000000Z),"CCC","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:21:00.000000Z),"DDD","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:22:00.000000Z),"EEE","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:22:20.000000Z),"EEE","Bad",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:22:40.000000Z),"EEE","Bad",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:27:00.000000Z),"FFF","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:27:20.000000Z),"GGG","Bad",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:27:40.000000Z),"AAA","Uncertain",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:28:00.000000Z),"HHH","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:30:00.000000Z),"III","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:32:00.000000Z),"JJJ","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:35:00.000000Z),"KKK","Good"
];
```

The result table I am looking for:
My conditions are:

```
let start = datetime(2023-03-22T10:15:00.000000Z);
let end =   datetime(2023-03-22T10:35:00.000000Z);
let resolution = timespan(1m);
```

[image]

```
Result table as Kusto data table:
datatable (StartTimestamp: datetime, ValueString: string, TotalCount: int, QualityGoodCount: int, QualityBadCount: int, QualityUncertainCount: int) [
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:15:00.000000Z),"AAA",1,1,0,1,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:16:00.000000Z),"BBB",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:17:00.000000Z),"BBB",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:18:00.000000Z),"BBB",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:19:00.000000Z),"BBB",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:20:00.000000Z),"CCC",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:21:00.000000Z),"DDD",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:22:00.000000Z),"EEE",3,1,2,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:23:00.000000Z),"EEE",3,1,2,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:24:00.000000Z),"EEE",3,1,2,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:25:00.000000Z),"EEE",3,1,2,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:26:00.000000Z),"EEE",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:27:00.000000Z),"AAA",2,0,1,1,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:28:00.000000Z),"HHH",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:29:00.000000Z),"HHH",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:30:00.000000Z),"III",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:31:00.000000Z),"III",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:32:00.000000Z),"JJJ",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:32:00.000000Z),"JJJ",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:32:00.000000Z),"JJJ",1,1,0,0,
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:35:00.000000Z),"KKK",1,1,0,0
]
```

I have tried using the Summarize operator, but it only takes me a part of the way. It does not backfill data from previous bin, nor does it return the bins of 1 minute.

```
let start = datetime(2023-03-22T10:15:00.000000Z);
let end =   datetime(2023-03-22T10:35:00.000000Z);
let resolution = timespan(1m);
myTableSource
| summarize Value = arg_max(StartTimestamp, ValueString), TotalCount=count(), QualityGoodCount = countif(Quality startswith 'Good'), QualityBadCount = countif(Quality startswith 'Bad'), QualityUncertainCount = countif(Quality startswith 'Uncertain') by bin(StartTimestamp, resolution)
```

I probaply need to use make-series with a combination interpolation function called series_fill_forward(). I just cant seem to get the syntax correct.

Hope there is someone out there, that can point me in the right direction.

Comment: I am able to generate the series of data, but having doubt on result table data you shared. Can you please explain how you are calculating TotalCount value for ValueString "EEE" and "AAA" where StartTimeStamp is "datetime(2023-03-22T10:27:00.000000Z)"?

Comment: also can you please explain each of those count columns in result table posted in question.

Answer (score 0):

This approach might not be the most efficient, but it seemed like the most straightforward. It will work well if your time range is not too large.

It doesn't perfectly match your desired result, though. Did I misunderstand what you had in mind?

```
// 1. Define parameters.
let start = datetime(2023-03-22T10:15:00.000000Z);
let end =   datetime(2023-03-22T10:35:00.000000Z);
let resolution = timespan(1m);
// 2. Build table of all timestamps we want to output.
let timestamps = range StartTimestamp from start to end step resolution;
// 3. Define data and summarize into bins.
let data = datatable (StartTimestamp: datetime, ValueString: string, Quality: string) [
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:14:00.000000Z),"AAA","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:16:00.000000Z),"BBB","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:20:00.000000Z),"CCC","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:21:00.000000Z),"DDD","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:22:00.000000Z),"EEE","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:22:20.000000Z),"EEE","Bad",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:22:40.000000Z),"EEE","Bad",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:27:00.000000Z),"FFF","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:27:20.000000Z),"GGG","Bad",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:27:40.000000Z),"AAA","Uncertain",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:28:00.000000Z),"HHH","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:30:00.000000Z),"III","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:32:00.000000Z),"JJJ","Good",
    datetime(2023-03-22T10:35:00.000000Z),"KKK","Good"
];
let dataSummary = data
| summarize arg_max(StartTimestamp, ValueString), TotalCount = count(),
    QualityGoodCount = countif(Quality startswith "Good"),
    QualityBadCount = countif(Quality startswith "Bad"),
    QualityUncertainCount = countif(Quality startswith "Uncertain")
    by bin(StartTimestamp, resolution);
// 4. Cross join using dummy column.
timestamps 
| extend dummy = 1
| join kind=leftouter (
    dataSummary
    | project-rename DataTimestamp = StartTimestamp
    | extend dummy = 1
) on dummy
// 5. Take the most recent data for each bin that occurred before or during that bin.
| where DataTimestamp <= StartTimestamp
| summarize arg_max(DataTimestamp, ValueString, TotalCount, QualityGoodCount, QualityBadCount, QualityUncertainCount) by StartTimestamp
| project-away DataTimestamp
```